# Neither 'BinaryExpression' object nor 'Comparator' object has an attribute 'days'

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I tried to use datetime model to select objects, but returns an error of *Neither 'BinaryExpression' object nor 'Comparator' object has an attribute 'days'* The code sare as follows:

```
model = Configure()
input_time = datetime.datetime(2021, 5, 10, 0)

t_tuple = model.DATABASE_DICT[128].query(BasketModel.rfid) \
    .filter(BasketModel.rent_time <= input_time) \
    .filter(BasketModel.last_order_no.startswith('ZK')) \
    .filter(BasketModel.status == 1) \
    .filter(BasketModel.is_del == 0)\
    .filter((input_time - BasketModel.rent_time).days <= 30 )\
    .all()
```

```
class Basket(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'basket'

    rent_time = Column(TIMESTAMP, nullable=False, server_default=text("CURRENT_TIMESTAMP"))
    rfid = Column(String(64), nullable=False, unique=True)
```

Comment: Time diff / interval handling is pretty DBMS specific, so which one are you using? And what are `input_time` and `BasketModel.rent_time`? Please don't answer in comments, but instead edit your question to include a [mcve].

Comment: Related: https://github.com/sqlalchemy/sqlalchemy/issues/5672